# resize font according to number if items in a container

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a div container which has a fixed size and I am dynamically loading icons in that. An icon is just another div.
I want to re-size the font inside the icon div depending on the number of icons loaded.
I tried to use {font-size: 4vw}, but that does not seem to work.
Is there another way of re-sizing the fonts?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do...but you can't size text by the width of the parent element....you'd need JS for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it is not possible with pure `CSS`, but since you are using `JavaScript`, why don't you set your `icons` `font-size` to `1em` and then just change the container's `font-size` every time you add or remove an `icon` from it?